# Incorrect jQuery UI Position outside viewport

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, position

I'm dynamically creating images on a user click and positioning those images relatively to another "main" image. When I add the image the main image inside the viewport, everything goes ok, but if the main image and by consequence the target position of the new image is outside the viewport, the placement is not set correctly, but instead has some offset.

I'm using the jQuery UI's Position API to achieve this, like the example below:

```
$("#imageID").position({
            "my": "left top",
            "at": "left top",
            "of": $("#mainImageID"),
            "offset": "0 0"
});
```

How can I make this placement correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Is `.position({";` a typo? Shouldn't it be `.position({`.

Comment: What applied CSS styles are there? What is the HTML structure?

Comment: @Scott - it was a typo in the post, i've edited it.

Comment: @JonAdams - regardless of the HTML or CSS, simply scrolling the target position out of the viewport and adding the image has different results than when adding with the target position inside the viewport. The HTML is somewhat complex, several divs inside each other till the image, regarding CSS the image doesn't have any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question seems to be a duplicate of this one below:

[jQuery UI position function problem when the parent div is not visible on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283779/jquery-ui-position-function-problem-when-the-parent-div-is-not-visible-on-the-sc)

The solution is to define the collision mode to none:

```
$("#imageID").position({
        "my": "left top",
        "at": "left top",
        "of": $("#mainImageID"),
        "offset": "0 0",
        "collision": "none"
});
```